# Sqlalchemy 0.7.10 silently omits duplicate entries in many-to-many relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm trying to deal with many-to-many relation using sqlalchemy 0.7.10. My problem is that alchemy silently omits duplicate entry inserts into association table. The desired behavior is to get DB Duplicate Entry error from db and notify the user.

Here are the models:

```
class Node(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "nodes"
    .....

class ZoneNodeAssociation(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "zone_node_association"
    node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'),
                     primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    zone_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('zones.id'),
                     primary_key=True, nullable=False)    

class Zone(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "zones"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True)
    nodes = relationship("Node",
                         secondary="zone_node_association",
                         backref="zones",)
```

And the action:

```
def zone_add_node(context, zone_id, node_id):
    session = get_session()
    with session.begin():
        zone_ref = _zone_get(context, zone_id, session)
        node_ref = _node_get(context, node_id, session)
        zone_ref.nodes.append(node_ref)
        zone_ref.save(session=session)
```

First time the association table entry is added as expected, but when I'm trying to add the duplicate it just ends with no error.

When I'm doing an insert directly to the association table like

```
session = get_session()
with session.begin():
    association_entry = models.ZoneNodeAssociation()
    association_entry.update({'zone_id': zone_id, 'node_id': node_id})
    association_entry.save(session=session)
```

It behaves as expected, but I don't like this way because in case one of id's doesn't exist I'm getting an Integrity error and I don't know which exactly Id is wrong. So I'd like to use the first approach instead.

All similar questions that I've found have inverted problem - they want to silently omit duplicates, but god damn I need the error! =)

I've also found something in sqlalchemy change logs:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org:8000/en/rel_0_7/changelog/changelog_05.html#change-1a61f53a8bf148ab3f8311330af61a4e
but as I understand it was fixed in 0.5 release, and I'm using 0.7.10

**Update:**

I've tried to play on a separate environment and got the same behavior. Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/max-lobur/6366708

Comment: Have you tried flushing inbetween?

Comment: Just tried zone_ref.nodes.append(node_ref)
        session.flush()
        zone_ref.save(session=session) and result is the same. I was thinking can it be some global SqlAlchemy config to specify that duplicates should be omitted? If so then how can I override it for my particular table

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right, since you did not provide all code. What I created does throw an exception: http://pastebin.com/QVF3Fzt0 Try it out and try to spot differences. If that does not help please create a complete example like mine that does not behave as intended.

Comment: As I understood from your sample you created the association using nodes.append the first time and using direct write to association table the second. But I always use nodes.append and for me It does not throw an exception when duplicate is being added. I made an example of direct usage of association table to show that it works as expected. But my problem appears when I use append. Anyway thank you for your time, I think I need to isolate my code from the project like your example and try again. I'm pretty sure the reason is some project-specific config.

Comment: I figured out that it's not project-related one, it behaves the same way in a separated environment. https://gist.github.com/max-lobur/6366708 this is what I tried. As far as I understood SA doesn't generate insert statement for association table when duplicate is added, so of course DB doesn't generate an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify lazy='dynamic' in relationship.

nodes = relationship("Node", secondary="zone_node_association", backref="zones", lazy='dynamic')